# Unable to clone ArrayList<MatOfPoint> elements

Tags: java, android, opencv, arraylist, clone

I am using the following code to clone my array:

```
aproximatedContours = cloneList(contours);
```

The body of method:

```
public static ArrayList<MatOfPoint> cloneList(ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours) {
    ArrayList<MatOfPoint> clone = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(contours.size());
    for(MatOfPoint item: contours) 
        clone.add((MatOfPoint) item.clone()); // Line 479
    return clone;
}
```

However, even though both contours and clone are type of ArrayList, and obviously their elements are type of MatOfPoint, I get the following error:

```
08-16 16:34:16.015: W/System.err(21747): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opencv.core.Mat cannot be cast to org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint
08-16 16:34:16.020: W/System.err(21747):    at com.example.objecttracker.ObjectTracker.cloneList(ObjectTracker.java:469)
08-16 16:34:16.020: W/System.err(21747):    at com.example.objecttracker.ObjectTracker.onCameraFrame(ObjectTracker.java:446)
08-16 16:34:16.020: W/System.err(21747):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
08-16 16:34:16.020: W/System.err(21747):    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:321)
08-16 16:34:16.025: W/System.err(21747):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happeining here?

Comment: Updated for your request

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an API bug in [`MatOfPoint`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html): It inherits its `clone` method from `Mat`, so when you call it, you're getting a plain `Mat` returned (and presumably only the superclass's fields copied). The overall semantics for `MatOfPoint` don't appear to be cleanly defined, and there's no mechanism for copying one.

Edit: If the native object handle contains all of the necessary data, you might be able to use `new MatOfPoint(Mat m)` as a copy constructor.

Comment: Possibly the [copy constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html#MatOfPoint%28org.opencv.core.Mat%29) is the way to go, but you'd need to check the source to see if it works correctly with `MatOfPoint` instances.

Comment: I am having a lot of troubles while using OpenCV for android. Is there any other good library for CV? You are sure that it is a bug? Could you also check my bounty question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073239/opencv-java-convexity-defects-computer-vision

Comment: @Marek Please don't use comments to ask further questions.

Comment: This is a bug in the sense that a class really shouldn't implement `clone()` unless it's `final`, and `Mat` also doesn't implement the `Cloneable` interface.

Comment: chrylis, accoring to Duncan Jones, new MatOfPoint(Mat m) will not help. So what should be correct way to have two independent list? I want to process second list that contain elements same as first list and I don't want to change first list elements. Would my code work if ArrayList would contain different elements? For example Point?

Comment: @Marek I didn't say it wouldn't help. I just recommended you looked at the source to confirm - have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

Clone is a very [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540792/effective-java-analysis-of-the-clone-method) thing and maybe not implemented correctly in opencv

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a library issue because MatOfPoint is oddly relying on Mat's clone method which will clone a Mat object that is not a MatOfPoint.

As a workaround you could try to not depend on the clone() method but explicitly build copies on your own (untested):

```
    // Use a copy ctor
    clone.add(new MatOfPoint(item));
```

Comment: Not working - MatOfPoint have same references so when I change clone elements list elements get also changed...

Comment: You could try to deep clone the values then. Maybe something like new clone.add(new MatOfPoint(item.toArray()));